# redering dynamic data from array of objects on an html page and want to flip the specific box. On front page i want to show image and heading

Tags: javascript, html, css, flip

I am rendering dynamic data from array of objects on an html page. i want to flip the specific box. On front page i want to show image and heading while on the back page i want to show the paragraph. I am attaching the HTML and JavaScript file.

**The HTML code**

```
<div class="row rwOneOurservices ourServicesContainer" ></div>
```

**JavaScript where I am rendering my data from an array of objects**

```
const FnRenderOurService = () => {
  if (ElourServicesContainer) {
    ElourServicesContainer.innerHTML = "";
    for (singleOurService of ourServices) {
      ElourServicesContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-10 ourServiceElement" onclick="FnShowService('${singleOurService.id}')" id="${singleOurService.id}">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
            <img
              src="${singleOurService.serviceImg}"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 col-12">
            <h5>${singleOurService.serviceName}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <p>
            ${singleOurService.serviceShortDesc}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
          `;
    }
  }
};
```

How to apply flip on every grid separately (might be on the basis of 'Id')?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].   If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Also please make shorter titles. No need to poste the entire question in the title

Comment: What do you  b "flip the box" ?

Comment: Also I strongly recommend you delegate instead of using inline event handlers